# Android Spinner - System view VS User view

Tags: android, spinner

I have been creating Spinner controls (Combo boxes/Drop downs) in one of my apps, and was surprised to find out how difficult it was to achieve all of the following features:

1. User facing Strings are externalized, taking advantage of strings.xml internationalisation (I18N) feature of Android.
2. Spinner selections operate using a System view, which facilitates not having to work with or map Strings to meaningful values (yuck).
3. User view to System view mapping should be easy, automated and minimal (i.e not hand rolled for every component).

Others have attempted solutions to this, but universally as far as I could see they suffer from one or many of the following problems:

1. UI code is creeping into their enum class which doesn’t belong there (messy), nearly all existing solutions suffered from this.
2. Hardcoded User facing Strings in their enum classes. Because these are not externalized you cannot do I18N using the stock Android features.
3. Authors typically make the Fragment or Activity an OnItemSelectedListener which perpetuates a common problem of inheritance for convenience, where composition is more appropriate.

I have developed my own solution which does this: http://www.androidanalyse.com/android-spinner-externalize-user-strings-mapped-to-system-enum/

**My question** is, have I missed something? This seems like something that should not have been this hard (which makes me feel like I'm possibly reinventing the wheel).

Below is some example code showing my solution in-use (which is available Apache 2 license from the link above).

```
String none = getString(R.string.none);
String light = getString(R.string.light);
String medium = getString(R.string.medium); 
String strong = getString(R.string.strong);
SpinnerUtil.createNewSpinner(view, R.id.wind, Arrays.asList(none, light, medium,     strong), WindLevel.values(),
  new SpinnerItemSelectedListener<WindLevel>() {
  public void onItemSelected(Spinner item, WindLevel value) {
    // Take whatever action you wish to here.
  }});
```

Comment: What is a "System view"? What is a "User view"? What "enum classes"?

Comment: System view is the view for the developer in the Java code, so when developing in the listener you receive a strongly typed (in code) system view (or developer view if you like), versus the externalized String user view. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The enums are any enum type you use to model your domain in code, my examples given include WindLevel, DaylightLevel etc. The example here: http://www.androidanalyse.com/android-spinner-externalize-user-strings-mapped-to-system-enum/ contains all the example code (including my sample enums) all under Apache 2.0

Comment: Your first comment makes no sense to me, sorry. An externalized string is not a `View`.

Comment: I call it the user view in that the externalized Strings are what the user views (user facing strings); not View as in a View component in an abstraction sense.

Comment: Interesting question/solution. Android is missing something like `getContext().getString(CharSequence translateThisString)` to solve this problem in a nicer way. The enums should not contain any i18n code, that´s for sure and therefore your solution seems to be the only one that makes sense, although it is far from beautiful.

Comment: I like your suggestion, that would be much nicer than my work around :) hopefully the Android team adds this feature soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `ArrayAdapter<WindLevel>`. Yes, you created a custom typed listener, but the regular event listener gets the `position` and can call `getItem()` on the `ArrayAdapter<WindLevel>` to get a `WindLevel` properly typed.

IMHO, the vast majority of `Spinner` widgets will be populated with material read in from a database, the Internet, or some other dynamic data source, rather than populated by some sort of enum with display values coming from static strings that can be internationalized ahead of time.

This is not to say that your code is useless: if you find it useful, then it was worth writing. And I am sure that there are apps out there that contain your targeted pattern (i.e., a `Spinner` backed by an enum or equivalent where the display values are known in advance and can be internationalized) who might find your solution useful as well. Every developer who writes enough code cooks up these sorts of helper classes and the like that help map an OS or framework model into something that better fits the developer's own mental model. So long as you are not perceiving any performance issues, it's all good.

Also, note that `OnItemSelectedListener` is an interface; implementing that interface on an existing class is not inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, I will review your suggestions and update my blog post/create a new one. You are of course right, implementing the interface is not inheritance. In the case discussed above, I maintain that implementing the UI interface in the enum as a work around is still ugly and obfuscates intent. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just as an addendum, the vast majority of spinners in my app (a internationalised decision support system) are known at development time and are baked in as enums so this approach is definitely high value for me.

Comment: If you use an ArrayAdapter<WindLevel> then the strings which are shown to the user will be the toString representation of the WindLevel instances which means the suggestion suffers from the same problems as identified in the post (with the same non-ideal work around solutions). Basically I think perhaps you nailed it when you've said that for my needs the code is required, but for those who's data primarily comes from the Database this pattern is obviously not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason nobody answered you is :

What problem are you trying to solve ? Spinners existed prior to your well designed attempt.

Why reinvent them in exactly the same way they exist in Android ?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

It is a beautiful wheel indeed you designed, but still, it is just a wheel :)

**UPDATE :**
I think I begin to understand what you did. This is interesting. I'm not sure why you did not go to the pattern implemented by the ListPreference with its entries and entryvalues.
In fact, I'm not sure I understand why the Android team did not go that route either.

In any case, it is worth proposing your idea to the Android framework. It is after all open source.

Comment: My code doesn't provide a custom spinner component, it leverages the existing Spinner objects provided by Android. That's basically what I was asking; is there a stock Android way of mapping user/system values with the default spinners, is my helper util really required? which basically just does a lookup by int index and uses reflection to have strongly typed handlers.

Comment: Edited my answer after further review of your idea.

Comment: I don't think the ListPreference is a good fit because you still deal with Object instances and require casting at the system view level, my proposal has a strongly typed system view. Thanks for linking me to ListPreference and PreferenceActivity, I had not seen this before.